# Folder picker in HTML with Flask for Uploads

Tags: python, html, flask

I am running a Flask app where the user uploads a file and must select the root folder path of where to upload the file on a network drive. This path is an IIS available network path and is also a network drive on all user's computers.

I want to dynamically show the available folders in HTML, even if new folders are created after the app starts.

I know this can't be done with pure HTML due to security but wanted to know if there was a way around this with Flask. The goal is to use Python to move the upload file to the choosen folder path.

I have tried:

```
<form><input type="file" name=dir webkitdirectory directory multiple/></form>
```

But this only works in Chrome. With the path choosen by the user I can pass this onto Python to copy the upload file to there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to modern browser limitations I decided to use JSTree as a solution.  And it is working very well.  It features a tree structure browser.  The structure is the result of outputting the folders as JSON.  You can add a search bar as well so the user can just type in a folder name to search.
Please see [JSTree https://www.jstree.com/](https://www.jstree.com/)

**How to implement this with Flask**

**HTML/JS:**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css">
  <div>
  <input class="search-input form-control" placeholder="Search for folder"></input>
  </div>
<script id="jstree1" name="jstree1">
                        /*Search and JS Folder Tree*/
                        $(function () {
                            $(".search-input").keyup(function () {
                                var searchString = $(this).val();
                                console.log(searchString);
                                $('#container').jstree('search', searchString);
                            });
                            $('#container').jstree({
                                'core': {
                                    "themes": {
                                        "name": "default"
                                        , "dots": true
                                        , "icons": true
                                    }
                                    , 'data': {
                                        'url': "static/JSONData.json"
                                        , 'type': 'GET'
                                        , 'dataType': 'JSON'
                                    }
                                }
                                , "search": {
                                    "case_insensitive": true
                                    , "show_only_matches": true
                                }
                                , "plugins": ["search"]
                            });
                        });

                        { /*  --- THIS IS FOLDER SELECTOR FOR ID "folderout" --- */
                            $("#container").on("select_node.jstree", function (evt, data) {
                                var number = data.node.text

                                document.getElementById("folderout").value = number;
                            });
```

**In Flask/WTForms** call on the id "folderout".  This will return the path to WTForms when the user clicks the folder.

```
folderout = TextField('Folder:', validators=[validators.required()])
```

**To Create the JSON JStree File using Python:**

```
import os

# path   : string to relative or absolute path to be queried
# subdirs: tuple or list containing all names of subfolders that need to be
#          present in the directory
def all_dirs_with_subdirs(path, subdirs):
    # make sure no relative paths are returned, can be omitted
    path = os.path.abspath(path)

    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if all(subdir in dirs for subdir in subdirs):
                result.append(root)
    return result

def get_directory_listing(path):
    output = {}
    output["text"] = path.decode('latin1')
    output["type"] = "directory"
    output["children"] = all_dirs_with_subdirs(path, ('Maps', 'Reports'))
    return output

with open('test.json', 'w+') as f:
    listing = get_directory_listing(".")
    json.dump(listing, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python** runs on your server, therefoere it will not be possible to use that to move the files on the client side. If you think about it, let's assume you manage to somehow (magically) send python commands to the clients to move files, do you know if they even have python installed to be able to interpret your commands?

**Javascript** on the other hand is running on client side and was used to achieve this. However, like you said, due to security reasons modern browswers won't allow that. If they would allow it then any website could potentially see your whole File System.

Here is an [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection/) that explains a bit why. Look up the File Upload Control section of it. Hope this makes things a bit clearer.

**EDIT**: after seeing your comment you could achieve that using os.walk. Beware it could be slow.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath): # for example "C:/Users/"
    for file in files:
        if file == (wantedFile):
            print(os.path.join(root,file))
            break
```

Comment: Thanks limbo for the help.  However I would just like the user to select the path while the server side moves the file.  The server has the same access to the network folder as the client so this won't be the issue.  In fact if the user was allowed to see the folder path from the server side this would accomplish what I'm looking to do as well.

Comment: hmm, you can use os.walk then to look for the file. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks this would help list the folders.  Now I just need to figure out how to create a dropdown like list and SelectField for the various folder paths.